# Failed to conver string to timestamp bigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert string to timestamp but haven't been successful.

My field (payment_at) string contains

```
01-10-2021 9:04:06
01-10-2021 11:48:19
01-10-2021 16:01:35
```

I tried convert using

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", payment_at)
```

and

```
CAST(payment_at AS TIMESTAMP)
```

but it shows error

[Error running query; Invalid timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFTpr.png)

Please help if I am doing anything wrong

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The format_string your provided does not match the timestamp string input.
Replace `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` with `"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"`

Documentation for the parse_timestamp function:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp

Documentation for supported format elements:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#supported_format_elements_for_timestamp

Comment: Omg I missed that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", "01-10-2021 11:48:19")
```

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp)